# insert form data into sql server database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner of web design. I have a database set up and just want to insert form data into my database using PHP. I have code like these but when click submit button it goes to PHP code page. Need help. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="test.php" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sumit'])){
 $Fname=$_POST['FirstName']; 
 $Lname=$_POST['LastName']; 
 mysql_connect("server", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test_name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `FirstName`,'LastName' VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')"); 
 Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; }
 ?>  

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a my test table test_name.</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean "It goes to PHP code base"?

Comment: there's an error.. you wrote $_POST['sumit'] instead of $_POST['submit']

Comment: Doesn't need your insert statement need a table name?

Comment: 1. change `action=''`
2. `mysql_query("INSERT INTO (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')");`
3. As you're learning, learn something good :) Skip `mysql_* `functions. Try `mysqli_*` or **PDO**

Comment: Do you save files in server ?

Comment: @lorenzo.marcon nice catch, please post it as answer..

Comment: @Fallen thx for the PDO, learned something new today

Comment: When i click submit button, nothing save in database and no error

Comment: I'm sure most people saying mysql not i is deprecated don't even know why...

Comment: Thank all. Now need do somereach about PDO :)

Comment: I start to suspect that your database is not ready, esp. not ready to take such insert statements. Did you create a database with a table that is declared to have FirstName and LastName columns? Can you add rows manually from the commandline?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `action=test.php` to `action=''` if you want to submit the form to the same page
2. Correct your sql query `mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')")`;
3. mysql_* functions are deprecated now. Skip mysql_* functions. Try mysqli_* or PDO
4. instead of `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` it's better to try `if($_SERVER['REQEST_METHOD']=="POST"){` to see if the form was submitted via POST method or not

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very interesting in web design, after I study HTML , CCS now I think I may go to PHP, but it is really difficult to google and find which the newest stuff. Now do some Research on PDO AND mysqli_*

Comment: Nothing actually save in my table.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

everything ok but you need to add one attribue look like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sumit">
```

missing table name

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (`FirstName`,'LastName') VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')");
```

[View w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: thank you very much. i fix all these thing but still nothing save in my table. maybe the coneection has problem

Answer (score 0):

Where have you set : `$_POST['sumit']` There is no input with such a name -> it is not set -> you never reach the code in "if".
Also forms do not have a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `$_POST['sumit']` instead of `$_POST['submit']`

Answer (score 0):

1. "it goes to PHP code page" => Do you save files in server? if so check the below points
2. Change `if(isset($_POST['sumit'])){` to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`
3. Change `mysql_query("INSERT INTO`FirstName`,'LastName' VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')");` to `mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename`FirstName`,'LastName' VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname')");` You are missing table name

Answer (score 0):

Your insert seems to lack a table name, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

change
`action="test.php"`
to your localhost server address

Answer (score 0):

error sumit should be submit

Check to ensure names in this [''] brackets are same in the database and the form html form of the value name you used to POST or any form you used. Capitalization matters.